# Receiving Change Notifications From another user's Calendar

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, azure-ad-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

**ENVIORNMENT**

---

- Outlook Desktop (Office 365);
- Exchange Server;
- Azure Cloud

**INITIAL CONDITIONS**

---

**USER_A** is **USER_B**'s assistant and manages **USER_B**'s calendar (Outlook Shared Calendar).  We would like to track the changes in **USER_B**'s calendar.   In Outlook/Exchange speak,  **USER_A** is a *delegate* of **USER_B**.


**GOAL**

---

When certain Outlook Calendar Items are modified, we'd like to call a Function App which will update a database.  The calendar could be a Shared Calendar, but not necessarily a shared Calendar.

**USE CASE**

---

**USER_B** is not logged in, but **USER_A** creates an appointment in **USER_B**'s calendar.

Even though **USER_B** is not logged in, we'd like to capture the change made by **USER_A** and update our database.  In other words, a change notification should fire for the shared calendar, even though the owner of that calendar is not logged in.

**QUESTION**
Does the Function App need "App" level permissions to do this?

Would the code look something like:

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/subscriptions
Content-type: application/json

{
   "changeType": "created",
   "notificationUrl": "https://webhook.azurewebsites.net/api/send/UpdateDataBase",
   "resource": "users/{a-user-id}/events",
   "expirationDateTime":"2020-10-20T19:23:45.9376913Z",
   "clientState": "bigSecret",
   "latestSupportedTlsVersion": "v3"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to get change notification in shared calendars, "Application" level permissions are required.

I found this here [How to subscribe calendar event if calendar is given delegated permission using ms-graph api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58271497/how-to-subscribe-calendar-event-if-calendar-is-given-delegated-permission-using/58312687#58312687)